# Interpretation of the Brauer group via projective bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have come across an intepretation of the Brauer group of a complex algebraic variety $X$ as the set of isomorphism classes of $\mathbb{P}^n$-bundles which are not of the form $\mathbb{P} (E)$, for $E$ a vector bundle on $X$. I was wondering if there is an (easy) geometric interpretation of the group operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group operation in terms of projective bundles can be formulated as follows: if $P$ and $Q$ are peojective bundles over $X$ you should take $P \times_X Q$ and take its "Segre linear hull"; this a projective bundle that corresponds to the sum of the elements of the Brauer group corresponding to $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a reference for the Segre linear hull?

Comment: I have no reference, but this is easy to construct etale locally and then glue.